# Bulk insert of list of dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have defined my model class like below:

```
class MedicalPlan(Base):
    __tablename__ = "medical_plans"

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False , primary_key=True)
    issuer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('issuers.id'), nullable=False)
    service_area_id = Column(Integer).... and so
```

I have created a session using below code using which I am doing most of my sql operations:

```
def get_session():
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/db')
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)
    return Session()
```

I have my list of dictionary which I want to insert as a bulk insert.

In [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements), I can see where I can insert using something like below:

```
connection.execute(table.insert(), [ 
        {'id':'12','name':'a','lang':'eng'},
        {'id':'13','name':'b','lang':'eng'},
        {'id':'14','name':'c','lang':'eng'},
    ]
)
```

My question is how can I perform such operation using my model class in the way I have provided the mapping.

Something like this does not work:

```
conn.execute(MedicalPlans.insert(), list_of_dict)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659142/bulk-insert-with-sqlalchemy-orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table of the mapped class should be available as

```
MyTable.__table__
```

hence `MedicalPlan.__table__.insert()` should work.

---

There are other options in the question linked to by Ilja, but most are not as efficient - `bulk_insert_mappings` would come close.

Comment: conn.execute(MedicalPlan.__tablename__.insert(), list_of_dict) gives me `'str' object has no attribute 'insert'`

Comment: By reading the answer very carefully, and comparing to what you just wrote.

Comment: it works ..thanks.. wanted to check , can I use it with Session object that I am creating??

Comment: @themaster Yes. `Session.execute`. Though you might also need some dirty handling...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Could you let me know , how to do this with `Session.execute`  ?