# How to execute UPDATE query with SQLAlchemy SQL-builder in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

If have a sqlalchemy database and want to run an update query. I thought I could just use the same method that I also use for SELECT commands.

Here's my code:

```
disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
chunksize = 20000
j = 0
index_start = 1

for df in pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=chunksize, 
                         iterator=True, encoding='utf-8'):
    df.index += index_start
    j+=1
    df.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
    index_start = df.index[-1] + 1

...

##NOW I WANT TO UPDATE A ROW
ts = pd.read_sql_query('UPDATE data SET score = ROUND(score,1)', disk_engine);
```

But this throws an error:

> result.pyc in _non_result(self, default)
>       918         if self._metadata is None:
>       919             raise exc.ResourceClosedError(
>   --> 920                 "This result object does not return rows. "
>       921                 "It has been closed automatically.",
>       922             )
>
> ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has
>   been closed automatically.

How can I update the database correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy: prevent automatic closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375666/sqlalchemy-prevent-automatic-closing)

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Answer (score 3):

If the exact string `UPDATE data SET score = ROUND(score,1)` is what you want to be executed, you should be able to execute that from a connection to `disk_engine`. For example:

**sqlalchemy 1.x** you can get away with just this:

```
conn = disk_engine.connect()
result = conn.execute('UPDATE data SET score = ROUND(score,1)')
```

**sqlalchemy 2.x**, transactions are forced upon inserts, updates, deletes:

```
from sqlalchemy import text 
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text('UPDATE data SET score = ROUND(score,1))')  
    conn.commit()
```