# Efficient Update of All Rows in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to update all rows in a table, by setting the value of one column `images` based on the value of another column `source_images` in the same row.

```py
for row in Cars.query.all():
    # Generate a list of strings
    images = [s for s in row.source_images if 'example.com/' in s]

    # Column 'images' being updated is a sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY(Text())
    Cars.query.filter(Cars.id == row.id).update({'images': images}) 

db_session.commit()
```

**Problem:** This appears to be really slow, especially when applying to 100k+ rows. Is there a more efficient way of updating the rows?

**Similar questions:**

[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270879/efficiently-updating-database-using-sqlalchemy-orm): This question involves updating all the rows by incrementing the value.

**Model Class Definition: `cars.py`**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from ..Base import Base

class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    images = Column(postgresql.ARRAY(Text))
    source_images = Column(postgresql.ARRAY(Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the operation to the DB, instead of fetching and updating each row separately:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, column, func

source_images = select([column('i')]).\
    select_from(func.unnest(Car.source_images).alias('i')).\
    where(column('i').contains('example.com/'))

source_images = func.array(source_images)

Car.query.update({Car.images: source_images},
                 synchronize_session=False)
```

The correlated subquery unnests the source images, selects those matching the criteria, and the [`ARRAY()` constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) forms the new image array.

Alternatively you could use [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.25.4.2.2.1.1.1):

```
source_images = select([func.array_agg(column('i'))]).\
    select_from(func.unnest(Car.source_images).alias('i')).\
    where(column('i').contains('example.com/'))
```

Comment: On this machine, using a local DB, it took ~5s to update 500,000 rows containing random source image arrays that contained "example.com/" with P >= 10%.