# SQLAlchemy ORM is not updating row

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm, mariadb-10.3

I am using SQLAlchemy ORM with MariaDB (mariadbconnector). The database updates with the add_conversation function but when trying to update a value it does nothing and there is no error. Instead of filter_by() I tried get() but then I received this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'answer_sent'
```

The row and column exist so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

```
def add_conversation(conversation_id, chat_start, chat_end, answer_sent, answer_accepted):
    new_conversation = Conversation(conversation_id=conversation_id, chat_start=chat_start, chat_end=chat_end,              
    answer_sent=answer_sent, answer_accepted=answer_accepted)
    session.add(new_conversation)
    session.commit()

add_conversation(19156050, 1645552829, 1645559831, False, False)

def set_answer_sent(conversation_id):
    convo = session.query(Conversation).filter_by(conversation_id=conversation_id)
    convo.answer_sent = True
    session.commit()
    session.flush()

set_answer_sent(19156050)
```

Comment: i believe you have to have an `.update()` call in there somewhere. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/278606/42346

Comment: I tried that before and it wasn't working and couldn't resolve the error that came up but I just tried it again and it WORKED:   `session.query(Conversation).filter_by(conversation_id=conversation_id).update({'answer_sent': True})...`Thank you for making me try again ;)

Comment: no problem! glad you got it working :) you can post an answer with the code that worked, it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @mechanical_meat

I just added `.update({'answer_sent': True})` to the end of `session.query` and removed the `convo` variable assignments as they are not needed anymore:

```
def answer_was_sent(conversation_id):
    session.query(Conversation).filter_by(conversation_id=conversation_id).update({'answer_sent': True})
    session.commit()
    session.flush()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).